# How do I unlock JTAG in LAUTERBACH?

Tags: embedded, lauterbach

I would like to use PRACTICE scripting language to unlock JTAG port by using Lauterbach debugger.
How may I unlock it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
&PASSWORD="0xCOFFEE 0xCOFFEE 0xCOFFEE"
SYStem.Option.KEYCODE &PASSWORD
```